# Ambari HDP throwing FileNotFoundException for mapreduce.tar.gz while submitting the mapreduce job

Tags: mapreduce, ambari, hdp

After installing a new Hadoop cluster using Ambari, I tried to submit a mapreduce job, but it failed throwing an error.

**Error:**

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://xx-xx-xxx-x:8020/hdp/apps/2.2.9.0-3393/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved after restarting all components from Ambari UI.