# Import data using Sqoop from Oracle database into local file system?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to import data local file system using Sqoop and I get the  following error. How can I resolve this?

```
$**sqoop import -fs local -jt local --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@orau20:xxxx:xxxx --username xxx --password-file xxxx --table xxxxx --target-dir /user/local/  -m 1**

Error :

 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/hdp/apps/3.1.0.0-78/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:641)
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing mapreduce clients on that node from HDP installation. You can install them through Ambari

Comment: As @cricket_007 suggested install required files. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687032/ambari-hdp-throwing-filenotfoundexception-for-mapreduce-tar-gz-while-submitting and https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Failed-to-submit-the-map-reduce-job-using-hive-cli/td-p/117894